# ServiceStack ORMLite JSON Deserialization multiple levels

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-text

I've got a class containing a Dictionary like this:

```cs
Dictionary<string,object> Data
```

I put data on multiple levels into here, such as:

```cs
Data.Add("simple",4);
Data.Add("object",new Dictionary<string,object>{{"key",4}});
Data.Add("array",new List<string>{"a","b","c"});
```

Then I .Save() it with OrmLite, which is setup to use JSON instead of JSV:

```cs
SqliteDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonStringSerializer();
```

Looking inside the stored data, using SQL, it looks like perfectly valid JSON.

```json
{
    "simple": 4,
    "object": {
        "key": 4
    },
    "array": [
        "a","b","c"
    ]
}
```

However, when I `Load()` the data back, it doesn't deserialize back to the original.

Here's a link to Gist Cafe, showing the problem:
https://gist.cafe/9ed2bbb3a6a0348f129c493887ae8170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `JsonStringSerializer` uses ServiceStack.Text **Typed** [JSON Serializer](https://docs.servicestack.net/json-format) which can't deserialize an `object` back to its original type since that type information is lost, all it sees is the runtime `object` Type which it leaves as a string since it doesn't know what other object it should deserialize to.

Which is why it's recommended that you serialize typed DTOs so the type information is preserved, e.g:

```cs
class CustomData
{
    public int Simple { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,int> Object { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to deserialize anonymous `object` data structures into untyped collections you can configure ServiceStack.Text to use [JS Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) to handle deserializing arbitrary JSON into untyped data structures by registering it with:

```cs
ServiceStack.JS.Configure();
```

Which I've done in this modified gist:

#### https://gist.cafe/953f2da51a5077ecf7b5109c14ec2c32

Which outputs the expected result:

```js
{
    Id: 1,
    Data: 
    {
        simple: 4,
        object: 
        {
            key: 4
        },
        array: 
        [
            a,
            b,
            c
        ]
    }
}
```

Whilst it works in this instance because you're using only serializing JSON data types, it wont work if your object dictionary contains complex types because all JS Utils can see is the raw JSON string without any type information, so it's only able to deserialize into untyped collections that matches the JSON object - which is why it's recommended to serialize Typed DTOs so the types are preserved.

Comment: I can't see Configure() in the gist -- did you publish? What I'd actually want is to use typed object for the whole object, except for Data (my actual case is an object with fields, then there is one "bag" of user data, that can contain about everything). Is it possible to specify Serialization/Deserialization for a single field like that?

Comment: @specimen apologies pasted wrong link, fixed now. Switching out to use different serialize impls isn't supported, it's only supported for object types since an untyped serializer like JS Utils is preferable to handle object types. Things you can do is impl your own [IStringSerializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack.Text/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsonSerializer.cs#L280), split into different fields or save the complex object as a JSON `string` and handling the deserialization yourself.

Comment: I've added the `JS.Configure` and it seems to work -- even with complex types. https://gist.cafe/39a719d0c5947c730a017d2133e6d811

Comment: @specimen It'll be able to parse any valid JSON object, but it's not going to be able to deserialize it back into the custom Type if that's what was used to serialize the JSON initially. If needed you can use [FromObjectDictionary](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#populating-types-from-an-object-dictionary) to convert the object dictionary into a C# POCO.

Comment: But if you look at the gist, you'll see that it successfully parses the JSON into Person and Address types. I'm impressed, don't know how it figured it out, perhaps by name match.

Comment: @specimen because that's still apart of the strong type that the Typed JSON Serializer is still able to deserialize, i.e. not in an object value in the `Dictionary<string,object>`

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers: It works perfectly to serialize and deserialize a typed object, but if I put a Person inside the Dictionary<string,object> it won't know to deserialize the Person (naturally). However using the standard serializer will add a `"__type"` into the JSON as necessary, and thus know how to deserialize even when the DTO is just object